# PHP: Whileloop return all rows

Tags: php, while-loop

I am having trouble in returning all rows from while loop. When checking with print_r($item) it's returning all rows but when I user return in while loop it is only returning first row. I think that is because it is return the loop at the first time.

So how can I return all rows.. here is what I am trying

```
while($item = db_assoc($query)){

    return '<p>'.$item['title'].'</p>';
}
```

The while loop is within the class method and I have to return the value so can't use echo

Thanks a lot....

Comment: Please read [the manual](http://php.net/return) : `If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call. ..... If called from the global scope, then execution of the current script file is ended. `

Comment: Yeah so actually this whileloop is within the class method.. so what I exactly want is to return final result including html for that method

Comment: Seriously ? Then why don't you declare a variable and add the titles to it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you say, you're returning after the first row. Try the following:

```
$output = '';

while ($item = db_assoc($query)) {
    $output .= "<p>{$item['title']}</p>";
}

return $output;
```

Comment: Just one question.. do I need to add blank variable? `$output = ''`

Comment: @pixelngrain that's not a smart question.

Answer (score 1):

try to Create New Array Or Create format for you want inside the While-loop

And Return it..

"return" it stops execution loop.

```
while ($item = db_assoc($query)) {
    $output .= "<p>{$item['title']}</p>";
}

return $output;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
while($item = mysql_fetch_array($runsql)){
            $data[]=$item['first_name'];
        }
        return $data;
```

it is because when you write return in loop it return with first value, 
but in print_r it shows all record . so we have to create an array of required field and then return it

```
Hope it will help you.
```

Try this.

```
    while($item = mysql_fetch_array($runsql)){
        $data.=$item['first_name']."<br/>";
    }
    return $data;
```

Comment: but in this case I have to again use any loop to render html.. right? it will give me an array output..??

Comment: yes. then you create a string with concatenate all value and then return that string..

Answer (score 0):

Return will simply get out of the loop that's why it prints only the first row. If you want to return it all, save them in a string and after the while loop just return that string.

Comment: You can do something like, consider your gonna put them in a string:  $arr=null;                                                    while($item = db_assoc($query)){
     $arr.=$item['title']."\n";
}                                                                           print_r($arr);

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement is causing it to break the execution of the loop.

Try this instead:

```
while($item = db_assoc($query)){

    $titles[] = '<p>'.$item['title'].'</p>';
}
```

And to access the titles, you can simply use a foreach loop:

```
foreach($titles as $title){    
echo "<p> $title </p";    
}
```